# each button opens a certain modal

Tags: javascript

I have various buttons and various modal I want each button to open his modal but my javascript doesn't work! Can you help me?

```
var modal = document.getElementsByName('ccc');


var btn = document.getElementsByName("myBtn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < modal.length; i++) {    
    btn[i].onclick = function() {
    modal[i].style.display = "block";
    }

}
```

if I write it in this way it works:

```
btn[5].onclick = function() {
    modal[5].style.display = "block";
}
```

it seems like the function doesn't get the i paramente rhe right way..

now it works but it doesn't close anymore:

```
for (let i = 0; i < modal.length; i++) {    
    btn[i].onclick = function() {
   modal[i].style.display = "block";
   }

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
        modal[i].style.display = "none";
    }

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal[i]) {
            modal[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Declare `i` inside the `for` loop instead, and use `let`. `let i = 0`. Never use `var` if you can avoid it, `const` and `let` have block scope rather than function scope, and are not hoisted - much more intuitive.

Comment: thank you! now the modal work! But I still have a problem they don't close anymore! this is the complete code:

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using `let` instead of `var` with asynchronous code, you don't want to assign a listener to the window every single time an iteration runs. Instead, assign a listener *once*, outside of the loop, and check to see if the `event.target` is a `modal`.

Also, convert `modal` to an array first, so you can use array methods on it:

```
modal = [...document.getElementsByName('ccc')];

for (let i = 0; i < modal.length; i++) {
  btn[i].onclick = function() {
    modal[i].style.display = "block";
  }
  span.onclick = function() {
    modal[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (modal.includes(event.target)) {
    event.target.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your `span`? Is there really just one of them, or does each modal have a separate one? You can't assign multiple `onclick`s to an element unless you use `addEventListener`.

Comment: each span is a x to close the modal so I have one for each modal